# What am i missing/using in the if statement of this method that causes an Illegal start of expression error?

Tags: java

My code below is good except for the if statement at the bottom which is commented out for identification purposes. I have tried changing and adjusting the syntax at least a dozen times. It should be simple enough but being a newbie I break everything I touch.
I have also posted the driver code at the bottom in case anyone would like to try to compile it to see if they can help.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
/***************************************************************************
*Cat.java
*Jonathan Nees
*
*Cha. 6 OOP       
 ********************************************************************************/

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Cat
    {
        private String name;
        private String breed;
        private int age;
        private double weight;
        private boolean declawed;


    public void setName(String name)
        {
        this.name = name;
    }

        public String getName()
        {
        return this.name;
    }


    public void setAge(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return this.age;
    }


    public void setWeight(double weight)
    {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public double getWeight()
    {
        return this.weight;
    }

    public void setBreed(String breed)
    {
        this.breed = breed;
    }

    public String getBreed()
    {
        return this.breed;
    }


    public void setDeclawed(boolean declawed)
    {
        this.declawed = declawed;
    }

    public boolean getDeclawed()
        {
        return this.declawed;
    }

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void display()
    {
        System.out.print("Enter the name of the Cat: ");
        this.setName(input.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Enter the age of the Cat: ");
        this.setAge(Integer.valueOf(input.nextLine()));
        System.out.print("Enter the weight of the Cat: ");
        this.setWeight(Double.valueOf(input.nextLine()));
        System.out.print("Enter the breed of the Cat: ");
        this.setBreed(input.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Does the cat have claws? True or False?: ");
        this.setDeclawed(!Boolean.valueOf(input.nextLine()));
    }

    public void result()
    {
        if (this.setAge > 3) & (this.setDeclawed() == true)
    {
         System.out.println("The cats over 3 with   claws are:");
         System.out.println("Name: " + this.getName);
             System.out.println("Age: " + this.getAge + "Years Old");
        }
//This if statement above is what I'm having trouble with.
    }
}
/*******************************************************************************    ******************
*CatDriver.java
*Jonathan Nees
*
*Cha. 6 OOP Driver
```

---

```
********************************************************************************

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CatDriver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Cat Cat1 = new Cat();
    Cat Cat2 = new Cat();
    Cat Cat3 = new Cat();

    Cat1.display();
    Cat2.display();
    Cat3.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.getAge() ` should be there. That's the whole point of using setters and getters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to add parentheses after `this.getName` and `this.getAge` in the last two `println` statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (this.setAge > 3) & (this.setDeclawed() == true)
```

You need to wrap the whole condition in parentheses:

```
if ( (this.getAge() > 3) && this.getDeclawed() )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing setDeclawed() == true change it to a getDeclawed

Answer (score 0):

Really easy fix, when making if statements, make sure that all conditions fit inside the opening and closing brackeys ( /* conditions */ );  Also, you might want to use getAge() instead of setAge ( for self-explanatory reasons).

```
if (this.getAge() > 3 && this.setDeclawed())
```

By the way, a single '&' is used for other things, binary operations and stuff.

Comment: This fixed the error I was get but now it's moved to another area of the if statement. Syntax is my worst enemy and I knew it would be parenthetical.

Comment: No worries! Keep coding, and you'll get much better!

Comment: here is what I'm getting now.                                                                                        System.out.println("Name: " + this.getName);
System.out.println("Age: " + this.getAge + "Years Old");

Comment: getName(); Don't forget the brackets!

Comment: it says unknown symbol on the dot before getName and the dot before getAge. Should they be called by this.age or this.name?

Comment: brackets :) is what you need.

Comment: That's when I got the new error, after you pointed out the issue with the parenthetical I realized they were missing.

Comment: That's when it hit the println syntax

Comment: //here is what I have now with your help.public void result()
 {
     if (this.getAge() > 3 && this.getDeclawed)
  {
   System.out.println("The cats over 3 with claws are:");
   System.out.println("Name: " + this.setName);
   System.out.println("Age: " + this.setAge() + "Years Old");
  }
 }

Comment: So, what is the issue?

Comment: it says unknown symbol on the dot before getName and the dot before getAge. Should they be called by this.age or this.name? I've tries get and set in this case and tried adding () after each call. Newb:)

Comment: try, getAge(); without "this"

Comment: cannot find symbol moves to the g in getName getAge

Comment: It's not the print statement then, it's something else. Ask around. If you're using Eclipse, try Ctrl + S, sometimes it's a stupid compiler thing that goes away.

Comment: this.name and this.age fixed it @BorisMediaProds! thanks again sir

Answer (score 0):

```
if (this.setAge > 3) & (this.setDeclawed() == true)
```

instead do this:

```
if ((this.setAge > 3) && (this.setDeclawed() == true))
```